# Transactional not rolling back JPA save in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, transactions

I am working on a spring boot app where I am using transactional and its not rolling back its changes when I throw a exception:

**My method:**

```
private BtoBWalletTransactionResponseModel doWalletOperation(BtoBWalletTransactionTypes transactionType, BtoBWalletTransactionRequestModel transactionRequest) {
            // DB Operation
            BtoBWalletTransaction savedTransaction = commonTransactionalService.finishWalletTransaction(userWallet, btoBWalletTransaction);
            log.info("wallet {} txn of amount {} for user {}",transactionType.name(),txnAmount,userId);
            // throwing a exception to rollback
            throw new RuntimeException("Time to Rollback");
            
        } catch(Exception e){
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            log.error("error while doing wallet operations for user {}",userId);
            throw new WalletException(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

**My common TransactionalService Interface:**

```
public interface CommonTransactionalService {

    BtoBWalletTransaction finishWalletTransaction(BtoBUserWallet userWallet,BtoBWalletTransaction btoBWalletTransaction);

}
```

**My Interface Impl:**

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Service
public class CommonTransactionalServiceImpl implements CommonTransactionalService {

    @Autowired
    private BtoBWalletTransactionRepo btoBWalletTransactionRepo;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public BtoBWalletTransaction finishWalletTransaction(BtoBUserWallet userWallet, BtoBWalletTransaction walletTransaction) {
        BtoBWalletTransaction savedTransaction = btoBWalletTransactionRepo.save(walletTransaction);
        btoBUserWalletRepo.save(userWallet);
        return savedTransaction;
    }

}
```

Now even when I am sending a `RuntimeException` the DB record is not getting rolled back.
Can someone help? stuck since hours here.

Comment: Have you enabled transactions properly?

Comment: Its automatically enabled right

Comment: Not necessarily and since you haven't shared that code there is way for us to know what's happening

Comment: You are catching Exception. What is WalletException? It's a Runtime or a checked Exception?

Comment: Its a RuntimeException

Comment: Do you perhaps have the wrong @Transactional? you need the one from `org.springframework.transaction.annotation` not `javax.transaction`. Also unless you require otherwise the @Transactional is generally added to classes not methods i feel

Comment: you are throwing a runtime exception and inside the catch block, you are rethrowing it again. if the WalletException is not a runtime exception you have to mention it in the @Transactional annotation explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Transactional is scoped, if you anotate a method (or class) as `@Transactional` all the methods this class calls wil also be transactional. and if within this transaction an exception occurs things wil be rolled back.

If however like in you example a non-transactional method calls a transactional one and after that call throws an exception the previous transactioned function wil not be rolled back as it's outside of the transactions scope.